# passing action method parameter to ActionFilterAttribute in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I know that I can use the filterContext to get to it. However, this is not very flexible if the action method parameter is named differently. This should work:

```
[HttpGet]
[NewAuthoriseAttribute(SomeId = id)]
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    ...

public class NewActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{   
    public int SomeId { get; set; }
    ...
```

but it does not (it does not even compile). Any ideas?

Comment: Attributes are metadata and as such can only have constant values.

Comment: I think I came across this whilst googleing. I guess I could pass the name of the integer down to the attribute and then look for it in the filtercontext. what do you think?

Comment: Are you planning to base some of the authorization on a value sent to the application?  Doesn't this give the user a chance to effect the authorization outcome?

Comment: No sorry - my actionfiltername was misleading. i have changed that.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Building on the answer from @Pankaj and comments from @csetzkorn:

You pass the name of the parameter as a string then check the filterContext

```
public class NewAuthoriseAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string IdParamName { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey(IdParamName))
        {
            var id = filterContext.ActionParameters[IdParamName] as Int32?;
        }
    }
}

[NewAuthorizeAttribute(IdParamName = "fooId")]
public ActionResult Index(int fooId)
{ ... }
```

Comment: What about if I want to pass the model state to this action filter?

Comment: the "ContainsKey" method  can throw an ArgumentNullException in case you decide to omit the "IdParamName" parameter. Be sure you check that: if (IdParamName != null && filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey(IdParamName))

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

I am assuming that you are looking to make the Alias of Parameter name. This is giving you the flexibility to have multiple Alias of your paramater Name.

[image]

**ActionParameterAlias.ParameterAlias Overloads**

[image]

If so, you can give alias like below.

```
[ParameterAlias("Original_Parameter_Name", 
                 "New_Parameter_Name")]
[ParameterAlias("Original_Parameter_Name", 
                 "New_Parameter_Name1")]
[ParameterAlias("Original_Parameter_Name", 
                 "New_Parameter_Name2")]
[ParameterAlias("Original_Parameter_Name", 
                 "New_Parameter_Name3")]
```

public ActionResult ActionMethod(Model ParameterValue)
    {
        return View(ParameterValue);
    }

---

### **Original Post**

Try this one.

**Attribute**

```
public class NewAuthoriseAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("id"))
        {
            var id = filterContext.ActionParameters["id"] as Int32?;
        }
    }
}
```

**Action Method**

Make sure to set the Parameter type nullable to avoid RunTime Crash.

```
[NewAuthoriseAttribute]
public ActionResult Index(Int32? id)
{
}
```

Comment: as I said - that's not an option and I am aware of this. The reason why I do not want to use this approach is that id can also be called a, b, c etc.

Comment: Then add the name of the ActionParameters key to the constructor of the attribute.