# Action filter attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, action-filter, custom-action-filter

Is it possible to have a ActionFilterAttribute parameters like this ?

```
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
```

For example I need to create something like this

```
[ValidateSession(Session.Required)]

public class ValidateSession : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    enum Session
    {
        Required,
        NotRequired
    }

    private Session _session { get; set; }

    public ValidateSession(Session session)
    {
        this._session = session;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add parameters to custom ActionFilter. For more information see 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530779/passing-action-method-parameter-to-actionfilterattribute-in-asp-net-mvc).